# Is there a way to make the "global" command carry into and through a discord.py command?

Tags: discord.py

```
global t
t = 0
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  while True:
    await ctx.channel.send(member.mention)
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
      try:
        if message.author == member:
          t = 5     #(A)
          return
      except:
        pass
    if t == 5:
      break
```

Line (A) shows an error. I assumed the problem was that the variable t was not carrying through the @bot.event, but it seems like even the global command does not work. Is there some other problem that I just don't see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

When defining `t`, you are already defining it at the module (global) level. Thus, the `global t` command is redundant.

Instead, you should use `global` inside each new local scope you want to use `t` in.

As of now, the statement `t = 5` creates a variable local to `on_message`. You probably want to edit the global `t`, which can be accomplished with the following edits to your code:

### Code

```py
t = 0
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  while True:
    await ctx.channel.send(member.mention)
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
      global t  # Since we are assigning t in this function, we must state to use t from the global scope
      try:
        if message.author == member:
          t = 5     #(A)
          return
      except:
        pass
    if t == 5:
      break
```

### Reference

[Scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)